# Facing Table of contents problem?

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting

Facing Table of Contents problem. On first page of Table of Contents no numbering but on the next It's start numbering with header n footer.

```
\documentclass[tikz,table,twoside,12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{PTSansNarrow}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[ruled, vlined, linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{censor}
\censorruledepth=-.2ex
\censorruleheight=.1ex
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[top=3.5cm, bottom=3.5cm, left=3.5cm, right=2.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{color}
\textwidth14cm
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.1,0.3,0.5}

\DefineVerbatimEnvironment%
{MyVerbatim}{Verbatim}
{gobble=0,label=\hspace{.85\textwidth},labelposition=all}

\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}%Sonny, Lenny, Glenn, Conny, Rejne, Bjornstrup and Bjarne
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{rotfloat}
\usepackage{subfloat}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
% load package with ``framed'' and ``numbered'' option.
\usepackage[numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{}
\fancyhead[R]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}


\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{gobble}% Remove page numbers (and reset to 1)
\clearpage
\title{\textbf{THESIS NAME}\\
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{logo.eps}
\end{figure}
}

\date{}
\author{\textbf{SUBMITTED BY:}\\\textbf{STUDENT NAME}
\vspace{5mm}
\\
\textbf{Supervised By}\\
\textbf{NAME}\quad
\vspace{10mm}
\\
\textbf{DEPARTMENT OF COMPUTER SCIENCE} \\\textbf{NAME OF UNIVERSITY}        \\\textbf{Session:2012-2013} }
\maketitle

\null
\vfill
\null
\vfill
\onehalfspacing
\newpage
\pagenumbering{roman}
\chapter* {PROJECT APPROVAL}
SAKASLJFSAJFKSAJFJEIJ S\KJ\\\\
\newline
COMMITTEE\\\\
\newline
\begin{flushleft}
External Examiner: \line(1,0){250}
\end{flushleft}
\begin{flushleft}
Comments: \line(1,0){250}
\end{flushleft}
\begin{flushleft}
Internal Examiner: \line(1,0){250}
\end{flushleft}
\begin{flushleft}
 Comments: \line(1,0){250}
\end{flushleft}
\begin{flushleft}
 Chairman: \line(1,0){250}
 \end{flushleft}
 \begin{flushleft}
 Comments: \line(1,0){250}
 \end{flushleft}

\chapter* {DEDICATION}
 KSAHDSAFH ASK JFASKJF

\chapter* {ABSTRACT}
 XCLSCSAJFSAFOSAFISADKFLASKFL;ASKSAKFLKSALKFS

\chapter* {ACKNOWLEDGEMENT}
LSAFLDSFJ SDAFJIASFAS JFSJAF SFSFAUI DSAF
\chapter* {AUTHOR'S DECLARATION}
ABC
\newline
Signature of Authors\\
\newline
ABC: \xblackout{forty       two}\\
\newline
ABC: \xblackout{forty     two}\\
\newline
Date: \xblackout{forty     two}\\



\newpage
\pagenumbering{gobble}% Remove page numbers (and reset to 1)
\clearpage
\tableofcontents

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\input{ch1}
\input{ch2}
\input{ch3}
\input{ch4}
\input{ch5}
\input{ch6}
\input{ch7}
\input{ch8}


\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\textbf{Bibliography}}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibk}


\end{document}
```

[image]